# How can I load data dictionary which is in the resources using QuickFIX/J

Tags: quickfixj

I use QuickFIX/J in my application. My data dictionary files stay in my resources folder in the jar file. In the FIX settings file, how can I give the data dictionary path to QuickFIX/J to load my data dictionary in the jar?

If I had a chance to load the data dictionary programmatically, I could do this, but I think I can't do it.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What happens if you use the DataDictionary constructor 
https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/2.0.0//quickfix/DataDictionary.html

Comment: How are you building your jar ? Secondly the location of the jar needs to be in the config file, where quickfixJ can read from. https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

You can place the DataDictionary file wherever you want in the server where the application is running but you have to specify the path of the DataDictionary in the configuration file.

eg:
`DataDictionary=path/Of/The/DataDictionary/File/datadictionary.xml`